# Unable to pass datatable as table variable to a stored procedure

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, stored-procedures, datatable

I am passing values from a list to a datatable and then passing the datatable to a stored procedure as a table variable . For some reason ,the values are not getting passed correctly in the Table variable.
I ran sql profiler and found that all the values are coming in as NULL

```
        DataTable dbRk1 = new DataTable("dbRk1");
        dbRk1.Columns.Add("val1", typeof(String));
        dbRk1.Columns.Add("val2", typeof(DateTime));
        dbRk1.Columns.Add("val2", typeof(Int64));
        dbRk1.Columns.Add("val3", typeof(Int32));
        dbRk1.Columns.Add("val4", typeof(Int64));
        dbRk1.Columns.Add("val5", typeof(Int32));
        dbRk1.Columns.Add("val5", typeof(DateTime));

        drk.x.ForEach(x => dbRk1.Rows.Add(x));
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection conn = null;
        using (conn =new connection...)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[proc]", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TableVariable", dbRk1);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

}

```
     Alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc]
    (
        @TableVar [dbo].[TableVar] READONLY
    )
    AS
BEGIN
Set nocount on
Declare @MYID INT
Declare @SOMEDate DateTime
Declare @NEWDate Date


select @MYID = some_id,
@SOMEDate = convert(date, db_some_date) from tbl_some
where someval = (select tb.val1 from @TableVar as tb);


Merge DeviceBillCycle as target
  using (Select x.val1, x.val2, x.val3,x.val4,
                        x.val5,x.val6, x.val7 from @TableVar as x)
  as Source

  on val_id = @MYID
  when matched and  @MYID !=NULL then

 update set      val1= Source.[val1],
                  val2=Source.[val2],
                  val3=Source.[val3],
                  val4=Source.[val4],
                  val5=Source.[val5],
                  val6=Source.[val6]

  when not matched and @MYID !=NULL then  
   insert  
   values (Source.[val1],
           Source.[val2],
           Source.[val3],
               Source.[val4],
               Source.[val5],
               Source.[val6],
               Source.[val7],
               @MYID
      )      ;
end
```

Comment: after drk.x.ForEach(x => dbRk1.Rows.Add(x));  Debug a couple values in dbRk1 to be sure.  And will post an answer where you don't use datatable.

Comment: Yes you are right. The values are not going in during drk.x.ForEach(x => dbRk1.Rows.Add(x));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a datatable is needless overhead.

If you have a list you can use it directly by implementing IEnumerable`<SqlDataRecord`>.
I always sort by the PK in the IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() to keep index fragmenation down.
The reason for the asynch is creating lastDocFTSinX is expensive and takes about as long as the insert.

I like that you can Debug in the IEnumerable`<SqlDataRecord`>.

```
SqlConnection sqlConnFTSindexInX = new SqlConnection(builder.ToString());
sqlConnFTSindexInX.Open();
SqlCommand sqlCmdFTSindexInX = new SqlCommand("InsertFTSindexInXTablock_TVP", sqlConnFTSindexInX);
sqlCmdFTSindexInX.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
AsyncCallback callbackFTSindexInX = new AsyncCallback(HandleCallbackFTSindexInX);
SqlParameter tvpParamFTSindexInX = sqlCmdFTSindexInX.Parameters.Add("@ItemTVP", SqlDbType.Structured);
tvpParamFTSindexInX.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
```

the next group is in a loop

```
while (isExecutingFTSindexInX)
{
    Thread.Sleep(10);
}    
docFTSinXsCollection = new DocFTSinXsCollection(lastSID, lastDocFTSinX);
tvpParamFTSindexInX.Value = docFTSinXsCollection;
sqlCmdFTSindexInX.BeginExecuteNonQuery(callbackFTSindexInX, sqlCmdFTSindexInX);
// the callback will set isExecutingFTSindexInX = false;


    public class DocFTSinXsCollection : List<DocFTSinX>, IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>
    {
        // used by TVP for fast insert
        private int sID;
        private IEnumerable<DocFTSinX> docFTSinXs;
        IEnumerator<SqlDataRecord> IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>.GetEnumerator()
        {
            var sdr = new SqlDataRecord(
            new SqlMetaData("wordID1", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int),
            new SqlMetaData("wordID2", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int),
            new SqlMetaData("sID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int),
            new SqlMetaData("Delta", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int));
            foreach (DocFTSinX oh in docFTSinXs.OrderBy(x => x.Word1).ThenBy(x => x.Word2))
            {
                sdr.SetInt32(0, oh.Word1);
                sdr.SetInt32(1, oh.Word2);
                sdr.SetInt32(2, sID);
                sdr.SetInt32(3, (Int32)oh.Delta);
                yield return sdr;
            }
        }

        public DocFTSinXsCollection(int SID, IEnumerable<DocFTSinX> DocFTSinXs)
        {
            sID = SID;
            docFTSinXs = DocFTSinXs;
            //Debug.WriteLine("DocFTSinXsCollection DocFTSinXs " + DocFTSinXs.Count().ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @Blam. Could you please explain how would i use docFTSinXsCollection = new DocFTSinXsCollection(lastSID, lastDocFTSinX);
I don't have any ID field in my table variable.
Also do you know why my method does not load values in the datatable ?thanks so much.

Comment: Just modify the constructor to not have the the ID.  If you don't have rows in the DataTable then need to fix drk.x.ForEach(x => dbRk1.Rows.Add(x));  The syntax for adding a row to a DataTable is not that compact.

Comment: Thank you @Blam .i fixed my foreach loop as below 
foreach (var someRecord in someReport)
            {
                var dr = someReport.NewRow();
                dr["val1"] = someRecord.val1;
                .......

                datatable.Rows.Add(dr);
            }